# AMANDA backup fails with: data read: recv error: shm_ring is cancelled

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, tape, amanda

I have an AMANDA backup process running nightly. About a month ago, we pulled  the config into AMANDA 1:3.5.1-build2 (ubuntu package) running on Ubuntu 18.04 (new hardware as well). In the past week the backup has failed twice with:

> data read: recv error: shm_ring is cancelled

Only finding one google hit on this. Anyone know what might be causing it? Not much turns up in `syslog` and not sure if the `Sense Key` error is cause, or effect.

**AMANDA email**

```
Date    : September 23, 2019 (8:31 AM)
    ...
    FAILED DUMP DETAILS:
      /-- kapernick /mnt/cache/daily.0/node1.test lev 0 FAILED [data read: recv error: shm_ring is cancelled]
      sendbackup: start [kapernick:/mnt/cache/daily.0/node1.test level 0]
      sendbackup: info BACKUP=/bin/tar
      sendbackup: info RECOVER_CMD=/bin/tar -xpGf - ...
      sendbackup: info end
      | /bin/tar: ./var/lib/lxd/unix.socket: socket ignored
      \--------
    ...
```

**Syslog**

```
Sep 23 08:31:05 kapernick kernel: [329302.736887] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Sep 23 08:31:05 kapernick kernel: [329302.736891] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, operation in progress
Sep 23 08:31:05 kapernick kernel: [329302.737961] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Sep 23 08:31:05 kapernick kernel: [329302.737963] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, operation in progress
Sep 23 08:31:05 kapernick kernel: [329302.740652] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Sep 23 08:31:05 kapernick kernel: [329302.740655] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, operation in progress
Sep 23 08:31:08 kapernick kernel: [329305.741326] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Sep 23 08:31:08 kapernick kernel: [329305.741330] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, operation in progress
Sep 23 08:31:11 kapernick kernel: [329308.741954] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Sep 23 08:31:11 kapernick kernel: [329308.741958] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, operation in progress
Sep 23 08:31:14 kapernick kernel: [329311.742487] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Sep 23 08:31:14 kapernick kernel: [329311.742491] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, operation in progress
Sep 23 08:31:17 kapernick kernel: [329314.743108] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
Sep 23 08:31:17 kapernick kernel: [329314.743111] st 11:0:1:0: [st1] Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, operation in progress
```

Answer (score -1):

Which storage device are you using? 
I think connectivity is causing the problem. Can you check the port availability using the following commands?

```
# sudo -u amandabackup amadmin <Backup set> config --print-source &> full_config_details
# grep -i port full_config_details
```